# Is there a way to increase node app render speed in heroku platform?

Tags: node.js, firebase, heroku, deployment

I have a node appp deployed on Heorku. The node app fronted usess vanila js  and ejs template to render html elements and firebase as it database.On development l tested everying on local host and everytning was fine and rendering html elements quicker but once deployed on Heroku its takes for ever to render my html elements.

I thought firestore was the cause for slow reponse. So whenn the server starts l pull the data needed from firetore and store it in an Array. like this :

```
var allnewsarr =[];
function getNews(){
    console.log('running')
    
    fs.collection('news').orderBy("timestap",'desc').get().then((snaps)=>{
        snaps.forEach((fillers)=>{
            allnewsarr.push(fillers)
        });   
      found = true;
        console.log(allnewsarr.length, "are the articles")
        
        // res.send(left[0].data())
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        repeat()
        console.log(error.message);
    })

}
```

```
server.listen(port,()=>{
    getNews()// data is extracted only when the server starts
    console.log(`The new logs ${port}`)}
    );
```

Comment: Are you running a production build on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it. The prolem was that l was choking the tcp sending it with large amounts of data .Gzip helped to compress and increased the speed 4 times faster